# In Airflow, how can I create a custom Operator that supports Jinja templating?

Tags: airflow, jinja2, etl

I'm trying to create a custom Airflow operator and I want one of its fields to support Jinja templating. I've read the documentation but it seems that there's still something that I don't get. Here's the code for my custom operator:

```py
class UtilETLStartJobRunOperator(UtilETLStartRunBaseOperator):
    template_fields = ('util_etl_start_run_uuid',)

    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(
            self,
            redshift_schema,
            redshift_conn_id,
            tgt_job_name,
            util_etl_start_run_uuid,
            *args,
            **kwargs):
        
        super().__init__(
            redshift_schema=redshift_schema,
            redshift_conn_id=redshift_conn_id,
            *args,
            **kwargs
        )
        self.util_etl_start_run_uuid = util_etl_start_run_uuid
```

This class inherits from `UtilETLStartRunBaseOperator` which in turn inherits from `BaseOperator` and implements the `execute` method.

The problem I'm having is that when I try to use Jinja syntax to run a task created using my custom operator, I get an error message saying `{taskinstance.py:1150} ERROR - 'ti' is undefined`.
Here's is how I'm defining my task:

```py
start_task = UtilETLStartJobRunOperator(
    task_id='start_etl_job',
    tgt_job_name='etl_job',
    redshift_schema='my_schema',
    redshift_conn_id='my_conn_id',
    util_etl_start_run_uuid=f'{{{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids="{previous_task_id}") }}}}', # assume previous_task_id is defined and contains the task_id of some upstream task
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag  # assume dag is defined
)
```

What should I do so my `{{ }}` Jinja expression renders correctly? I think it has something to do with the `provide_context` parameter. I'm setting it to `True` here, but it doesn't seem to make any difference. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: First of all, you may declare a function you need with all required parameters and decorate it with [`@task` decorator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/tutorial/taskflow.html). It makes everyting much clearer and readable: just series of function calls instead of xcom hell like `ti.xcom_pull('something_i_dont_know_because_taskgroup_nesting')`. A context becomes available via `**kwargs` argument passed to each executable. But for your specific question you need to remove f-format and remove extra pair of `{{` - should be two of them.

Comment: I'm using Airflow 1.10 though and using the TaskFlow API (@task) is not supported. The 4 {'s are used to escape the Jinja syntax inside fstrings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was using the value of the templated field inside the operator's constructor and at that point, 'ti' isn't defined yet, hence the `'ti' is undefined` error.

Answer (score 0):

`provide_context` is a setting specific to the `PythonOperator` and is no longer required since Airflow 2 (same goes for `@apply_defaults`). Why you're getting that error could have multiple reasons, but you correctly set the `template_fields` to make `util_etl_start_run_uuid` template-able.

Below is a complete working example. I left out code unnecessary for this example:

```py
import datetime

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.models import BaseOperator
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator


class UtilETLStartJobRunOperator(BaseOperator):
    template_fields = ("util_etl_start_run_uuid",)

    def __init__(self, util_etl_start_run_uuid, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.util_etl_start_run_uuid = util_etl_start_run_uuid

    def execute(self, context):
        print(f"util_etl_start_run_uuid = {self.util_etl_start_run_uuid}")


with DAG(
    dag_id="so_77276990",
    schedule=None,
    start_date=datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1),
):
    task1 = PythonOperator(task_id="task1", python_callable=lambda: "test")

    previous_task_id = "task1"
    start_task = UtilETLStartJobRunOperator(
        task_id="start_etl_job",
        util_etl_start_run_uuid=f'{{{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids="{previous_task_id}") }}}}',
    )

    task1 >> start_task
```

Here `task1` returns the value "test". This is then stored in an XCom, you can inspect this in the Airflow UI:

[image]

Next, your `UtilETLStartJobRunOperator` fetches this value using `f'{{{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids="{previous_task_id}") }}}}'` and runs `execute()`, which simply prints the given value in this example.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm using Airflow 1.10.14 though, so the @apply_defaults have to stay. I tried removing the provide_context as well and it didn't make any difference (which is expected, right?). Do you have any ideas on what I should look into in order to investigate the 'ti is undefined' thing?